# How do I reduce the gaps between cells in HTML tables?

Tags: html

I am new to coding and I am using a table with a border of 0 to format my page. How do I make the gaps between cells smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [border-spacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-border-spacing) property (or the [border-collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-border-collapse) property if you want to remove them entirely).

Note also that cells may have [padding](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-padding), that you might wish to set to zero (as space between the content and edge of a cell can look like space between cells if there isn't a border present).

Answer (score -1):

Try cellspacing and cellpadding
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_29.html

Comment: CSS has been a standard for long enough that we can avoid using this presentational markup.